# Using an H-Bridge like a comparator

Tags: dc-motor, h-bridge, comparator

I'm wondering if there's a way to use an H-bridge like a comparator- That is, if one input is greater voltage than the other, then the attached motor spins one way, and vice versa, and it doesn't spin at all if the input voltages are equal. I know I could do this using separate comparators, but I'm just wondering if there's a simpler way.

Comment: This is a bit vague too give an answer, so ... It Depends! Please post a link to the H-Bridge your considering, then there may be a more definite answer. There are multiple ways to implement an H-Bridge, for example it could be one of many ICs, discrete MOSFETs, MOSFETS+driver, BJTs, etc. It is often a design goal that they have [Hysteresis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hysteresis), so there may be a relatively large voltage range where one or both inputs can change, and there is no change of output. A SWAG: a comparator is simpler to use to get specific behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

> doesn't spin at all if the input voltages are equal

If the voltages are equal on a comparator, the comparator output is indeterminate - a comparator outputs 1 or 0 depending on inputs being greater than each other; when inputs are the same it won't output some constant mid range value.

Based on your understanding of comparators and my understanding of H bridges I'd say the answer to your question is no, a H bridge would not be easily made to behave like a comparator. If on the other hand to want to use two comparators (aka a window comparator) then the two outputs could control a H bridge to do what you want.